# Can I use the graphql pagination cursor as an unique indentifier?

Tags: javascript, pagination, graphql, apollo-client

The main question is in the topic basically but I'd like to describe the problem in a bit details. 
I'm working on the Apollo graphql pagination which is cursor-based and in my Cache, I should define the *merge* function to combine the existing and incoming data. Every data object has the common graphql pagination structure:

```
{
        "totalCount": ...,
        "pageInfo": {
            "startCursor": "...",
            "endCursor": "...",
            "hasNextPage": true,
            "__typename": "..."
        },
        "edges": [...],
}
```

I need to override the existing data like: *pageInfo*, *totalCount*, etc. by the same properties from the *incoming* but in the case of *edges* I need to carefully merge the existing and incoming items. To make it more elegant and to avoid duplicates I'd like to iterate over the incoming items and check if every item is unique. eg. if the *existing* edges don't contain items that exist in the *incoming*.

So I'm wondering if I can use the graphql pagination cursor that exists in every node as a comparison argument. I know that I can use the Item's ID but if it's possible to use the Cursor value as well, I could avoid to using the *deeper* property level of the edge's item

Here is an example of the data structure:

```
{
    "listArticles": {
        "totalCount": 22,
        "pageInfo": {
            "startCursor": "NjE2N2ZlMmI4N2NiNDczMGY0N2U5MGQ5",
            "endCursor": "NjE2ZDkzYTg0NDA5MWYyN2E0MmFkMGM5",
            "hasNextPage": true,
            "__typename": "PageInfo"
        },
        "edges": [
            {
                "cursor": "NjE2N2ZlMmI4N2NiNDczMGY0N2U5MGQ5",
                "node": {
                    "id": "6167fe2b87cb4730f47e90d9",
                    "commentsThreadId": "6167fe2b87cb4730f47e90d8",
                    "__typename": "Article"
                },
                "__typename": "ArticleEdge"
            },
            {
                "cursor": "NjE2ZDkzYTg0NDA5MWYyN2E0MmFkMGM5",
                "node": {
                    "id": "616d93a844091f27a42ad0c9",
                    "commentsThreadId": "616d93a844091f27a42ad0c8",
                    "__typename": "Article"
                },
                "__typename": "ArticleEdge"
            },
        ],
        "__typename": "ArticleConnection"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using cursors as unique identifiers, although they may end up uniquely identifying nodes. They should just be used for what they are: opaque strings used to locate nodes within pages.

As far as I know, depending on their implementation, two nodes cannot share one same cursor, but two cursors could be used for one same node.

I would just go "one level deeper" and use the actual item ids.

Comment: Thank you @sp00m, it's a brilliant and very informative explanation. To be honest, I haven't known about such technical nuances regarding cursors. I appreciate this info a lot.